# BeautifulSoup - replacing string not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a node of type `NavigableString` and I want to replace the contents. According to documentation, it should be like this:

```
node.string = 'new string'
```

however, if I inspect it doesn't work:

```
print unicode(node)        ---> prints 'old string'
node.string = 'new string'
print unicode(node)        ---> should print 'new string' but prints 'old string'
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `replace_with()` method to replace string.

From official documentation, it says

> You can’t edit a string in place, but you can replace one string with another, using replace_with()

```
node.string.replace_with("new string")
```

You can check [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring).

**EDIT**

As you mentioned `node` is a `NavigableString`, you don't need to change its `.string` attribute. You should do -

```
node = "new string"
```

If node is a `tag` then you should change its `.string` attribute.

Comment: thanks!!! it's confusing because for Tag you can change the .string variable directly https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string

Comment: As you mentioned `node` is a `NavigableString` try this - `node = "new string"`. Not sure though.

Comment: that just assigns a string to the variable node?